# Dynamically update MySQL table in Python in linear time

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I have an existing table with a large number of entries and I want to calculate a new column for every row. I have only found the following solution. This works, but it's slow as it needs to scan most of the entries of the table.

What I would like is a way to:

- Read a row
- Calculate the value for new column based on contents of row
- Update into database

This way it would only go through the table once and would have linear complexity.

```
        cursor.execute("SELECT tweet FROM Table")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row is not None:
            vader = analyser.polarity_scores(row)
            sentiment_vader = vader["compound"]
            cursor2.execute(
                    "UPDATE Table SET sentiment_vader = %s WHERE tweet = %s LIMIT 1",
                    (sentiment_vader, row[0]))
            kody.cnx.commit()
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: If you have an index on `tweet` it shouldn't need to scan the table for each update.

Answer (score 1):

The main performance issue I see is that you should not commit for each row update as this adds an overhead. You should commit in the end of the while or after a batch.

```
while row is not None:
   ...
else:
   kody.cnx.commit()
```

Also, if the `tweet` column is not indexed just create an index on that column in order not to make a table scan during the update.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so first, not to critize the other answers, which are correct, given a generalized assumption that you have to do it in Python.

However, when you really have bulk volumes, chasing after a client-side, in-Python answer is often not the best approach.  Since you want to update all the rows, *assuming you can translate your polarity_scores algorithm into sql*

```
UPDATE Table 
SET sentiment_vader = <sql expressing your polarity_scores>;
```

would be the best performer.  There is no back and forth with the database and everything gets committed at once.

Now, I am not saying it's easy or even possible.  Often in these cases, even assuming the algorithm can be expressed in SQL, you may have to use work tables to store intermediate results and there is a lot of SQL going on.  It's a different skill set than writing Python code.

But, if you truly need performance and you have large volumes, letting the server do the job on its own, in SQL, can be the way to go.  That can be done via a series of sql commands, or using stored procedures.

In a previous job, we had explicit instructions to avoid loop and write constructs in client code and code reviews would almost always reject it on bulk data manipulations.  I remember advising a colleague that doing a select-update on a table with potentially up 5M rows seemed a bad approach.  He certainly ignored me at the time, but 3 months later his mission-critical code had all mysteriously shifted to a no-loop approach.

Note however one key conceptual difference:  an error on a server-side update would rollback the transaction for all rows indiscriminately, whereas you could maybe choose to commit row-by-row using a loop construct like yours (even though you don't want it in your case).

The expected performance profile server-side is usually considerably better than O(n) linear time.  Most of the time you should be nearly at constant O(1) time complexity, once you have correctly written your queries and indexes.  Linear time to update, for a RDBMS vendor, would be commercial suicide.  Usually what you see is a near constant time, followed by non-linear and hard-to-predict performance degradation past very high volume thresholds.  You will see linear time earlier when indices can't be used and for your queries the RDBMS falls back to performing full-table scans.

Answer (score 0):

Is this MySQLdb ? Maybe you can try an `executemany`.

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT tweet FROM Table")

cursor2.executemany(
   "UPDATE Table SET sentiment_vader = %s WHERE tweet = %s LIMIT 1",
   ((analyser.polarity_scores(row)["compound"], row[0]) for row in cursor)
)

kody.cnx.commit()
```

Just as @abc suggested above, you should also make sure `autocommit` is set to False, so that each query isn't committed separately during the `executemany`.